# javax.usb.UsbNotActiveException: Setting is not active exception

Tags: java, usb, libusb, usb-drive

I work with "custom" USB device which has unusual structure(as for me its unusual)
For communication I try to use usb4java-javax library.
Problem in next:

1. when i get interface from active configuration, it does not has
   endpoints, but contain 2 interfaces/settings inside.

> UsbConfiguration configuration = device.getActiveUsbConfiguration();[image]
>
> UsbInterface iface = configuration.getUsbInterface((byte) 0);
> [image]
>
> iface = iface.getActiveSetting().getSetting((byte) 1);
> [image]

2. When i receive needed settings and claim interface, i receive *javax.usb.UsbNotActiveException: Setting is not active*  exception

> iface.claim(); //here is my exception

So, I decide that's I need claim interface before settings receiving, and there are no exception on interface claiming, but when i want to open pipe
i receive another exception *javax.usb.UsbNotActiveException: Pipe is not active.*

> UsbPipe pipe = iface.getUsbEndpoint(mOutAddress).getUsbPipe()

Can you explain whats wrong in my approach(wrong claiming order) or any other tricks?
Thanks

Comment: you found any solution?

Comment: @RiyasValiyadan, libusb through NDK

Comment: can you please share some code snippet or repo links, it would be very useful...

Comment: @RiyasValiyadan, it was done for commercial product so I can't. But it's not hard to find a docs for libusb cuz it's very common lib. You can check this one 
https://github.com/libusb/libusb/tree/master/android